# How to write a question in tcbox in a horizontal line

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox

I want to write the second question which is 5+ 4 in the horizontal line after the first question, how can I write that?

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,title={\hskip 70mm Add the following numbers},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue]    


\begin{tabular}{cc}
    
    & 2\\
+   &3\\
&\rule{10mm}{.3mm} \\
&\rule{10mm}{.3mm} \\
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{cc}
    
    & 5\\
    +   &4\\
    &\rule{10mm}{.3mm} \\
    &\rule{10mm}{.3mm} \\
\end{tabular}

 



    \end{tcolorbox}    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the empty lines between the two tabular environments.

Comment: was your problem solved

Comment: @Sachin would you like to accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,title={\hskip 60mm Add the following numbers},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue]    


        \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
            
            &   2               &   &   5               \\
        +   &   3               &+  &   4               \\
            &\rule{10mm}{.3mm}  &   &\rule{10mm}{.3mm}  \\
            &\rule{10mm}{.3mm}  &   &\rule{10mm}{.3mm}  \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sachin would you like to accept and upvote the answer